# RecordType.Name not working in SOQL

Tags: apex, soql, opportunity, account, record-type

When I run the query  `select id, RecordType.name from account` , I am getting the records but when I run the similar below query, I am getting error.

`select id, RecordType.name from opportunity`

The error is

**Didn't understand relationship 'RecordType' in field path. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.**

What might be causing the error since it is running fine for account and not for opportunity?

Comment: Do you have any record types defined on `Opportunity`?

Comment: Probably a safe bet to just post that as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `RecordTypeId` field is not added to an SObject until you define at least 1 record type for that SObject.

Having that (standard) relationship field is a prerequisite for being able to query `RecordType.Name` (i.e. you cannot traverse a relationship that doesn't exist).

Comment: It did not have any record type ! Thanks Derek.